# three.js animated sprite / offset texture for shadow shader

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, shader, shadow

i'm using http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ for animated sprite,
for the shadow, i'm using this shader

```
    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShaderDepth">
        uniform sampler2D texture;
        varying vec2 vUV;
        vec4 pack_depth( const in float depth ) {
            const vec4 bit_shift = vec4( 256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0, 1.0 );
            const vec4 bit_mask  = vec4( 0.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0 );
            vec4 res = fract( depth * bit_shift );
            res -= res.xxyz * bit_mask;
            return res;
        }

        void main() {
            vec4 pixel = texture2D( texture, vUV );
            if ( pixel.a < 0.5 ) discard;
            gl_FragData[ 0 ] = pack_depth( gl_FragCoord.z );
        }
    </script>

    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShaderDepth">
        varying vec2 vUV;

        void main() {
            vUV = 0.75 * uv;
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        }

    </script>
```

to get juste one sprite

```
    vec2 tailleA = vec2( taillex , tailley);  // 1/22 num sprite horiz  & 1/3 Vert 
    vUV = vec2( tailleA[0] * uv[0] , (tailleA[1] * uv[1]) );
```

How can i get the offset forthe texture from the shader automatic generated from three.js ?
How to get animated shadow ?

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think the question is really just how to get an animated shadow in threejs?